# How to change a radian calculation to output degrees?

Tags: java, parsing, math

I have used the following calculation to calculate a mesaurement but the problem is it outputs the calculation in radians instead of degrees.My question is how do I convert the calculation to output degress instead.I'm aware of the Math.toDegress method but I'm having trouble inplmenting it in this situation.This is my onCreate where the calculation is done:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            String getoffsetlength = data.offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            String getoffsetdepth = data.offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            String getductdepth = data.ductDepth.getText().toString(); 

            double tri1,tri2;
            double marking1,marking2;


            double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);//length
            double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);//depth
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);//duct depth


            marking1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2));
            tri1 = Math.atan(off2 / off1);

            tri2 = (180 - tri1) / 2;
            marking2 = off3 / Math.tan(tri2);



            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
            myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            //make a toast 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Calculating!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 



        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: **What** runtime errors?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: division on 0 I suppose

Comment: ýour code has nothing to to with an radians to degree conversion. You show something, probably wrong code, where you use the toDegrees()

Comment: okay,I'm gonna reword this question as it wasn't a great attempt on my part.

Comment: `180 - tri1` is almost certainly where it first went wrong.  You have to do all the calculations in radians until a final conversion to degrees, essentially.

Comment: okay,could you give me a code example of how I would do this? What I tried was wrapping each marking1 and marking2 in the Math.degree method like this :` marking2 = Math.toDegree(off3 / Math.tan(tri2));` But that didn't work for me..

Comment: The `marking` variables are unitless; it is the `tri` variables that need to be kept in radians.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use: `Math.toDegrees(double angrad)`

From Doc:

Returns the measure in degrees of the supplied radian angle.
The result is `angrad * 180 / pi`.

Answer (score 0):

The radians to degree conversion is just a multiplication with a constant factor,
either use `Math.toDegrees()` or define it yourself if you have any reasons for that:

```
public static final double TO_DEGREES = 180.0 / Math.PI;
public static final double TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180.0;
```

But your code looks wrong:

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2)));
```

This could be simplified as

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.sqrt(off1 * off1 + off2 * off2));
```

this then is easier recognizable:
You calculate a distance with Math.sqrt(off1 * off1 + off2 * off2) 
but use this value as angle which you pass to toDegrees.

I doubt that is is correct.

To answer your comment:
You convert a value "angleRadians" to degrees with

```
Double angleDegrees = Math.toRadians(angleRadians);
```